# Github markdown image with multiple links

Tags: github, svg, markdown, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I have a requirement to show a high level architecture image in markdown on Github. I would like different segments of the image to link to specific markdown files.

I thought I could do this with .SVG, as SVG supports multiple links embedded in the graphic. However, when I embed my SVG in Github with this syntax:

```
![High Level Technical Architecture](../images/highLevelArchitecture.svg)
```

The links I have throughout the .SVG no longer seem to be exposed, and instead the SVG becomes a single hyperlink to the specific SVG file on GitHub.

Is there a smart way to achieve an image mapped with multiple links on Github markdown, or do I have to mosaic many smaller images... ugh.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links only work if the SVG is inline or embedded as an iframe. Iframes will work on GitHub pages, but not on the standard repo page.

```
<iframe src="../images/highLevelArchitecture.svg"></iframe>
```

Comment: Right, GitHub's sanitation filter will strip out iframes, so this is not a solution on GitHub.

Comment: I expect the [sanitation filter](https://github.com/jch/html-pipeline/blob/master/lib/html/pipeline/sanitization_filter.rb) will also strip out some, if not all, of the svg tags when trying to inline the image as well. It may not be possible on GitHub.

Comment: Note that the above linked filter [used to be linked](https://github.com/github/markup/commit/56a58500418779ee3e06db2bfcd86654acbf2ce7) from [github/markup](https://github.com/github/markup#github-markup), where GitHub documents there markup processing. Since the link has been removed, we can't be certain they still use that filter, but whatever filter they do use is likely very similar in behavior.

Comment: To make sure that there are no misunderstandings: On GitHub **pages** (which the tags indicate this question is about), iframes are **not** stripped from markdown. [See it live](https://th-we.github.io/iframe-demo/).

Comment: thanks. I missed the [github-pages] tag. Yeah, my comments don't apply on GitHub pages