# Does Azure Devops wiki markdown support image maps or similar elements?

Tags: hyperlink, wiki, imagemap, github-flavored-markdown, azure-devops-wiki

I am using Azure Devops wiki to document software and hardware architecture. I want to integrate an overview diagram (vector graphic or pixel based) with **multiple** clickable regions (e. g. via image map) used as hyperlinks to other wiki pages containig more detailed information.
I tried to use img tags containing png or svg files. But image maps are obviously not supported by Azure Devops Wiki. Hyperlinks in the original svg files seem to be ignored or stripped.

I even tried to split my png image into smaller rectangles and to put them into table cells with hyperlinks but the result is not convincing as I did not succeed to completely remove the margins or borders between the cells.

Mermaid diagrams are not an option in this case as I want to use existing blockdiagrams created in Visio or Powerpoint.

Are there any known solutions for the Azure Devops Wiki?

Comment: Please consider tagging this `azure-devops-wiki`. I would have done it but there is a five tag limit and I did not want to remove any of your tags.

Comment: @ScottWelker: Thank you for the tagging hint, I followed your recommendation.

Comment: Findings related to an iframe based solution: 
1) Similar question in stackoverflow but related to github-pages: Solution there is to use iframes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55511998/github-markdown-image-with-multiple-links. 
2) Community Voting for iframe support in Azure Devops Wiki: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/allow-iframe-elements-to-be-embedded-in-wiki-pages/608314

Comment: Similar question for a gitlab environment: https://forum.gitlab.com/t/how-to-create-imagemap-in-gitlab-markdown-file/37225